# Batch Move based on filename without Delimiters, String Only

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, cmd, delimiter

**Okay, Windows 7 Enterprise x64 here with a Windows batch file question. I am a somewhat basic user with little knowledge of batch file creation. I've modified existing scripts I've found online to my use, that is about it.**

I have a piece of software that dumps it's output to a folder with file names concatenated from the project title, current system date, current system time, and project settings.

It will export two files in this format every time the project is saved:

```
PROJECTTITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11__A_B_C.iges
PROJECTTITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11__A_B_C.step
```

The A, B, and C representing switches used in the software that are specific to the project. These may exist or may not exist as in the file name can be _R_F or _R_F_Z etc. 
"PROJECTTITLE" can literally be anything. This is where my problem arises using delimiters. You could potentially have file names like all of the following (using real examples from users):

```
11475shacklebody_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F.iges
11475shacklebody_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F.step
test_EFMflow_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_Z.iges
test_EFMflow_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_Z.step
untitled16_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R.iges
untitled16_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R.step
#14drop_wire-edm_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F_Z.iges
#14drop_wire-edm_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F_Z.step
prooftestwithoutupperlandsimproved-4_2016_10_07__09_45_11.iges
prooftestwithoutupperlandsimproved-4_2016_10_07__09_45_11.step
```

What I want to do is move both the IGES and STEP files from the output folder on the C drive to a new folder on a networked drive with name based on "PROJECTTITLE," creating that folder if needed. I have already task scheduled a -delim based batch to run every night, but found delimiters to not be sufficient for my use.

While it seems like an easy job to do with delimiters, looking for the first underscore, I have had projects with underscores in their names that screws up the folder naming. Since delimiters only work for individual characters, not strings, I have been looking for examples of batch files I can adapt to my use with no luck finding any similar to what I want to do that do not use delimiters.

It seems simple, search for string "_2016," in filename, and take all characters before "_2016" and create a new directory, placing files containing those characters in that folder. I am lost as to how to do this without delimiters though.

What I have working so far, using delimiters looking for underscores, creating folders and moving to those folders on a mapped drive:

```
for /f "delims=_" %%V in ('dir /b /a-d C:\Output\*_*.iges') do (
 mkdir "I:\ENG\PARTS\%%V" 2>nul
 move "C:\Output\%%V_*.iges" "I:\ENG\PARTS\%%V" >NUL 2>nul
 move "C:\Output\%%V_*.step" "I:\ENG\PARTS\%%V" >NUL 2>nul
)
```

It is a very simple batch file for what it does, but falls flat on it's face with titles containing underscores.

***A few things:***

Searching for `_2016` would mean the batch file would need yearly maintenance. Could we either search for system %YEAR% or somehow search for `"_####_##_##_"` with something like a regular expression to get away from searching for system date or a specific year?

**EDIT:**
While not ideal as the switches are useful, I found a way in the software to not export the project specific switches at the end of the file name. So now the export would be:

```
PROJECTTITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11.iges
PROJECTTITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11.step
```

Which I know I can trim from right, what, 21 characters, use that name to make a folder and search the directory for all files containing that trimmed string.

It still would be nice to figure out how to search for the specific string though with the switches intact. I am willing to learn, so throw all explanations of your code you can at me.

**Double (Late) EDIT:**
First, thank you all for answering this, I deeply appreciate your help.

Double underscores in the the filename are quite rare, but do happen, probably due to typos. It becomes more of an issue with the volume of files I'm planning to move with this. The software runs on maybe 100 user machines with 20 or so being heavy users, each saving up to maybe 1000 files a day. The software will automatically save in increments, as the user runs the simulation. I'm trying to give them a way to collaborate and view each other's simulation results over the network (that we actively encourage them to use) and it figures that the software is hard coded to output to the C drive (for "performance" as the vendor tells me). I'm looking into scheduling the files to move every 15 minutes on every PC in their OU instead of nightly to give a near-real-time view on what they are working on.

Another option I explored was symbolically linking the output folder on each machine to the software's folder network drive, but found that this really doesn't solve the user's "organization" issue, putting like project runs in the same folder. This also has the issue of not allowing them to save a project out of the office without VPN, which some users do do, then move their files over when they get back in the office.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The optional switches are always single letters only, right?

Comment: Could the PROJECTTITLE part also contain two consecutive underscores `__`?

Comment: The optional switches are always a single letter in our use, from what I have seen. I know there are plugins that we might use in the future that add different switches though. And yes, the PROJECTTITLE can, and has had two underscores. User entry is hard to control. I've had  to learn to work around their ways than teach them "the right way to do it" sadly enough. Assume any string of characters possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next batch script should do the job even if a file name contains `cmd` poisonous characters like *space* or  `%` *percent sign* etc.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_fouts=C:\Output"           your setting
set "_fouts=D:\test\39924063"    my setting 

for /F %%G in ('wmic OS get localdatetime ^|find "."') do set "_fyear=%%G"

pushd "%_fouts%"
  set "_fyear=%_fyear:~0,4%"
  call :doDir
  set /A _fyear -= 1
  call :doDir
popd

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:doDir
rem debugging output echo(%_fyear%
for /f "delims=" %%V in ('
  dir /b /a-d "*_%_fyear%_*.iges" "*_%_fyear%_*.step" 2^>NUL') do (
    set "_fname=%%~nV"           filename without extesion
    set "_fexte=%%~xV"           extesion only
    call :doAll
)
goto :eof

:doAll
    call set "_ftail=%%_fname:*_%_fyear%_=%%"
    call set "_fproj=%%_fname:_%_fyear%_%_ftail%=%%"
    rem debugging output echo("%_fproj%" "%_fname%" "%_fexte%"
    ECHO mkdir "I:\ENG\PARTS\%_fproj%" 2>nul
    ECHO move "%_fname%%_fexte%" "I:\ENG\PARTS\%_fproj%\"
goto :eof
```

**Output** (note that operational `mkdir` and `move` commands are merely displayed for debugging purposes using `ECHO mkdir` and `ECHO move`, respectively):

```
==> dir /B /S "D:\test\39924063" /S
D:\test\39924063\#14drop_wire-edm_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F_Z.iges
D:\test\39924063\#14drop_wire-edm_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F_Z.step
D:\test\39924063\%PROJECT TITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11__A_B_C.iges
D:\test\39924063\%PROJECT TITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11__A_B_C.step

==> D:\bat\SO\39924063.bat
mkdir "I:\ENG\PARTS\#14drop_wire-edm"
move "#14drop_wire-edm_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F_Z.iges" "I:\ENG\PARTS\#14drop_wire-edm\"
mkdir "I:\ENG\PARTS\%PROJECT TITLE"
move "%PROJECT TITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11__A_B_C.iges" "I:\ENG\PARTS\%PROJECT TITLE\"
mkdir "I:\ENG\PARTS\#14drop_wire-edm"
move "#14drop_wire-edm_2016_10_07__09_45_11__R_F_Z.step" "I:\ENG\PARTS\#14drop_wire-edm\"
mkdir "I:\ENG\PARTS\%PROJECT TITLE"
move "%PROJECT TITLE_2016_10_07__09_45_11__A_B_C.step" "I:\ENG\PARTS\%PROJECT TITLE\"

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~nV`, `%~xV` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`set "_fyear=%_fyear:~0,4%"` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: This works beautiful. I'll look into adding lines to remove %, = etc. in the filename outright before running. I've seen a few of our users use "%" to refer to features changed in their design for testing. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if I am lucky or what as I know there is no luck involved in this, but I seeded some really messed up names with "%," "__," AND "=" somewhere in the PROJECTTITLE. Somehow the folder was created exactly as it should be and the files were moved no problem. I'm not sure why this works or even if it should at all?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
REM (
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*__*" '
 ) DO (
IF /i "%%~xa"==".iges" CALL :process "%%a"
IF /i "%%~xa"==".step" CALL :process "%%a"
)
REM )>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:: Process filename "%1"
:process
SET "fullname=%~1"
SET "junk=%fullname:*__=%"
CALL SET "project=%%fullname:%junk%=%%"
SET "project=%project:~0,-13%
ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%project%"
ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%~1" "%destdir%\%project%\"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

This approach simply performs a directory list without directorynames (`/a-d`) of each file in the source directory that contains a double-underscore. Each filename matching is assigned to `%%a` and if the extension part (`%%~xa`) is one of the targets, then process the filename.

Processing consists of removing all of the characters before the double-underscore and then removing that junk part from the full name, giving project+date. Remove the last 13 characters and you have your project name.

Will have problems with any filename containing certain symbols like <kbd>%</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd> but should be fine with underscores.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the code, you have no idea how much more useful this becomes to me. As I mentioned (very late, ashamedly), double underscores do happen in the "PROJECTTITLE," but are fortunately rare. It seems like it would be difficult to remove a double underscore from just the "PROJECTTITILE" without wrecking the rest of the filename as it is difficult to identify where the title ends and the generated date starts when the title can literally be anything. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the PROJECTTITLE part of the file names does not contain two consecutive underscores, you could use the following script, which splits off the first occurrence of `__` and everything after (so the time part and the optional switches are removed), using a standard `for` loop rather than `for /F`; then it splits off another 11 characters (hence the remaining date part), using sub-string expansion:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=."
set "_TARGET=."

for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%F in ('
    pushd "%_SOURCE%" ^&^& ^(
    dir /B /A:-D ^
        "*_????_??_??__??_??_??*.iges" ^
        "*_????_??_??__??_??_??*.step" ^
    ^& popd^)
') do (
    call :PROCESS "%%F"
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  val_file
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FILE=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("!FILE:__=";"!") do (
    endlocal
    set "ITEM=%%~I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT
if defined ITEM (
    set "ITEM=!ITEM:~,-11!"
    md "%_TARGET%\!ITEM!" 2> nul
    if not exist "%_TARGET%\!ITEM!\!FILE!" (
        move /Y "%_SOURCE%\!FILE!" "%_TARGET%\!ITEM!\" > nul
    )
)
endlocal
endlocal
exit /B
```

---

Finally I come up with a script that is able to handle even files whose PROJECTTITLE part contain `__` on their own. It splits off the last occurrence of `__` and everything after (so the optional switches are removed, if any, or the time part is removed otherwise), using a standard `for` loop rather than `for /F`; then it splits off another 21 characters (hence the remaining date and time parts), or, if no optional switches were present, just another 11 characters (hence the remaining date part), using sub-string expansion:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=."
set "_TARGET=."

for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%F in ('
    pushd "%_SOURCE%" ^&^& ^(
    dir /B /A:-D ^
        "*_????_??_??__??_??_??*.iges" ^
        "*_????_??_??__??_??_??*.step" ^
    ^& popd^)
') do (
    call :PROCESS "%%F"
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  val_file
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FILE=%~1"
set "BASE=%~n1"
set "NAME=" & set "ITEM="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("!BASE:__=";"!") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%E in ("!NAME!!ITEM!__") do (
        endlocal
        set "NAME=%%E"
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
)
if defined NAME (
    set "NAME=!NAME:~2,-2!"
    echo("!ITEM!"| > nul findstr /R "^\"[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]\"$" || (
        if defined NAME set "NAME=!NAME:~,-10!"
    )
    if defined NAME set "NAME=!NAME:~,-11!"
    if defined NAME (
        md "%_TARGET%\!NAME!" 2> nul
        if not exist "%_TARGET%\!NAME!\!FILE!" (
            move /Y "%_SOURCE%\!FILE!" "%_TARGET%\!NAME!\" > nul
        )
    )
)
endlocal
endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Double underscores in the the filename are quite rare, but do happen, probably due to typos. Thank you though. I should have been a bit more timely getting back to you guys/gals to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This version assumes there will not be an instance of `_YYYY_` in the `PROJECTTITLE`.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

(Set OutDir=I:\ENG\PARTS)
(Set SrcDir=C:\Output)

If Not Exist "%SrcDir%\" Exit/B 1
If Not Exist "%OutDir%\" Exit/B 1
For /F "EOL=Y" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Year') Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "ThisYr=%%B")
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where "%SrcDir%:*_%ThisYr%_*.iges"') Do (
    If Exist "%%~dpnA.step" Call :Sub %%~nA)
Exit/B

:Sub
Set "BigTit=%~1"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('CMD /Q /C "Call Echo %%BigTit:_%ThisYr%_=&:%%"') Do (
    If Not Exist "%OutDir%\%%A\" MD "%OutDir%\%%A"
    Move "%SrcDir%\%~1*.*" "%OutDir%\%%A">Nul)
```

***Edit***, there is no need to export without the potentially useful project switches using the above code.

Comment: This might be the best bet, as the users typically rely on the automatically generated file date in the filename to know the time created, almost never putting their own date in the name.

Comment: And it works very well, thank you. I wish I can give two "best" answers as this gets the job done as well as JosefZ's for me. I just had more time with JosefZ's code.